# More efficient non-parametric ancova formulation?

Tags: r

I'm attempting to analyze the difference (or lack there of) of two linear regressions in R. I've always used the T.aov() function from fANCOVA for this; however, I'm dealing with obscenely large data this time around and T.aov() is taking literal DAYS to run. I don't have days remaining before my deadline anymore...

Is there a more efficient equivalent of T.aov(), or perhaps a more efficient way of coding it out using T.aov()?

My current formulation is fairly simply: `T.aov(x=data$descriptor, y=data$response, group=data$category, B=1)`

reproducible example using iris: `T.aov(x=iris$Sepal.Length, y=iris$Petal.Length, group=iris$Species,B=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T.aov() implements a permutation test, ideal for cases where parametric assumptions are violated. Though it has reduced assumptions, it is heavy on computational resources. If your dataset is large and your computational resources limited, then you should compromise and use the parametric version (see below):

```
library(fANCOVA)

data(iris)
spec = iris$Species
levels(spec) = 1:3

start_time <- Sys.time()
T.aov(x=iris$Sepal.Length, y=iris$Petal.Length, group= spec, B=200)
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time # 0.8088191 secs

start_time <- Sys.time()
lm.mod = aov(iris$Petal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Length + spec)
summary(lm.mod)
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time # 0.005981207 secs
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and I do understand your argument. The issue is my data do indeed violate parametric assumptions, and with 8million rows the severity of those violations are fairly severe. Should I take from this that there's no more efficient way to do it via non-parametric?

Comment: Maybe you can transform your data to alleviate the violations? log-transform, sqrt?